# Luarocks on windows not recognizing my lua_libdir

Tags: lua, luarocks

i want to install nngraph on lua using luarocks 
using this code

```
luarocks --from=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/ install nngraph
```

but it's give me an error 
it said :

> Error: Failed finding Lua library. You may need to configure LUA_LIBDIR.

does anyone have same experience? can you solve it ?

this was my config-5.2.lua :

```
rocks_trees = {
    { name = [[user]],
         root    = home..[[/luarocks]],
    },
    { name = [[system]],
         root    = [[d:\shared\ta\_bootstrap\_install\]],
    },
}
variables = {
    MSVCRT = 'MSVCRT',
    LUALIB = 'D:\\Shared\\TA\\_bootstrap\\_install\\lib\\liblua.dll.a',
    LUA_LIBDIR = 'D:\\Shared\\TA\\_bootstrap\\_install\\lib'
}
verbose = false   -- set to 'true' to enable verbose output
```

Comment: I just play with LR on windows. It works quite well. But I use MSVC compiler. Try to define lualib just like `liblua.dll.a`. Also may be it worth define lua_dir, lua_incdir and lua_bindir

Comment: @moteus i'd tried that too. but nothing came good :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your issue ? I would like to know the resolution .

Comment: @Ken sorry but no. so i've changed to linux that better with LUA and trying python and i've done my project.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `config-5.2.lua` file located in one of the searched paths? I installed the stand-alone binaries (with Lua version 5.3), which searches for `C:/Program Files (x86)/luarocks/config-5.3.lua` & `%APPDATA%/luarocks/config-5.3.lua`. Neither of these files existed on my system & I had to create one manually. Running the `luarocks` command without any arguments will show you where it searches. If you want to use a custom location, you can set the `LUAROCKS_CONFIG` environment variable.

I was able to get mine working by adding the following variables to my configuration (**Note:** I am using MinGW/GCC compiler):

```
rocks_trees = {
    { name = [[system]], root = [[C:/Development/Lua53]] },
}
variables = {
    LUA = 'C:/Development/Lua53/bin/lua',
    LUA_BINDIR = 'C:/Development/Lua53/bin',
    LUA_INCDIR = 'C:/Development/Lua53/include',
    LUA_LIBDIR = 'C:/Development/Lua53/lib',
    CC = 'gcc',
    LD = 'gcc',
}
```

The `CC` & `LD` variables are only necessary if it has trouble finding the compiler or linker (defaults to `mingw32-gcc` on my system).

Sources:

- http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaRocksConfig
- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2015-12/msg00172.html
- https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/config-file-format

I hope this helps.

**Edit:** If all else fails, you may want to have a look at [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/). It is a Lua distribution with its own package management system & includes LuaRocks & some other libraries/utilities pre-installed. I haven't tried it yet, but I plan to.

Comment: thankyou sir. But i'd failed many times and trying any config that are on stackoverflow. this one too. So i've given up and try in linux and python for better.