# LuaRock Visual Studio Command Prompt Error

Tags: visual-studio, lua, minecraft, opencomputers

I try to run `luarocks install luafilesystem` command in `Visual Studio Command Prompt`. But it says "Error: Failed finding Lua library. You may need to configure LUA_LIBDIR".

Why am i getting that error?(This time i got it Piglet :))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Luarocks on windows not recognizing my lua\_libdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026115/luarocks-on-windows-not-recognizing-my-lua-libdir)

Comment: searching the web for error messages usually yields several solutions. it is very unlikely that you're the first to run into any problem.

Comment: Well i searched but it looks like i don't know how to search or don't know how to use internet at all.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica but the thing is inside my lua/lib dir there is a luarocks folder. Shouldn't lib dir contain lua52.dll?

Answer (score 0):

LuaRocks cannot find a Lua library and needs one to install the luafilesystem module.

You could indicate your Lua library to LuaRocks using the `--lua-dir` command argument:

```
luarocks --lua-dir C:/bin/lua-5.3.5 install luafilesystem
```

Note that there is several way to indicate the Lua's libraries dir to LuaRocks, please check the LuaRocks documentation.

You could find pre-compiled Lua libraries and executables [here](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/).

The luafilesystem module is based on C source code and needs to be transformed into a dynamic library prior the installation.

Generating a dynamic library, such as `lfs.dll` or `lfs.so`, requires to compile the C source code then to link the result, such as `lfs.o`, against the Lua library.

Comment: So now it says;" 'mingw32-gcc' " is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/lfs.o. How do i overcome this problem and why this happens?

Comment: In addition to the Lua library, you need to setup the compilation tool chain.

Comment: As explained in the [LuaRocks documentation](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows): To compile many Lua packages, you will also need a C compiler.

I do not use MSVC so I cannot help you. You could start by checking if the MSVC compiler is available where you launched LuaRocks.